# MongoDB - Full Text Index - Full Text Search - stemming

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

I noticed that if I enter the value 'seasons' in a full text search enabled string field of some collection, then MongoDB finds this value when I query for 'season'. But if I enter something more complex like e.g. 'mice' or 'criteria', it does not find these values when I query for 'mouse' or 'criterion' respectively. Is that normal and are there any clear rules what MongoDB is able to stem and what not?

```
[test] 2014-03-30 18:25:09.551 >>> db.TestFullText7.find();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53389720063ab25d2d55c94c"),
        "dt" : ISODate("2014-03-30T22:13:52.717Z"),
        "title" : "mice",
        "txt" : "mice"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5338994c063ab25d2d55c94d"),
        "dt" : ISODate("2014-03-30T22:23:08.259Z"),
        "title" : "criteria",
        "txt" : "criteria"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("533899c5063ab25d2d55c94e"),
        "dt" : ISODate("2014-03-30T22:25:09.551Z"),
        "title" : "seasons",
        "txt" : "seasons"
}
[test] 2014-03-30 18:25:13.295 >>> db.runCommand({"text" : "TestFullText7", "search" : "season"});
{
        "queryDebugString" : "season||||||",
        "language" : "english",
        "results" : [
                {
                        "score" : 2,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("533899c5063ab25d2d55c94e"),
                                "dt" : ISODate("2014-03-30T22:25:09.551Z"),
                                "title" : "seasons",
                                "txt" : "seasons"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "nscanned" : 1,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "n" : 1,
                "nfound" : 1,
                "timeMicros" : 148
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
[test] 2014-03-30 18:25:22.406 >>> db.runCommand({"text" : "TestFullText7", "search" : "mouse"});
{
        "queryDebugString" : "mous||||||",
        "language" : "english",
        "results" : [ ],
        "stats" : {
                "nscanned" : 0,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "n" : 0,
                "nfound" : 0,
                "timeMicros" : 110
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
[test] 2014-03-30 18:25:30.986 >>> db.TestFullText7.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.TestFullText7",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "test.TestFullText7",
                "name" : "$**_text",
                "weights" : {
                        "$**" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 1
        }
]
[test] 2014-03-30 18:25:45.228 >>>
```

Comment: I am using MongoDB version 2.4.8.

Comment: Peter, I am experiencing [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766998/stemming-does-not-work-properly-for-mongodb-text-index) with stemming using MongoDB 2.4.8. Using your example, searching for document that contains word "seasons" using text index does not work (regardless of search string). Only if the document contains "season" does the search return it. I enabled text search, created a text index (ensureIndex) and use full text search (runCommand). What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses the Snowball stemming library. Unfortunately, this looks to be one of the limitations of this library.

You can see the pages for the english stemmer 
[here](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html). Compare the vocabulary + stemmed equivalent page and you can see "Mouse" becoming "Mous" and "Mice" still remaining "Mice".

You can see MongoDB's use of Snowball in their codebase [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/third_party/libstemmer_c) and [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stemmer.h#L38)

Comment: Thank you. Could you just point me to some authoritative references which indicate that MongoDB is using the Snowball stemming library?

Comment: No problem. Added a pair of links to my answer.