# Stemming does not work properly for MongoDB text index

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing, full-text-search, stemming

I am trying to use full text search feature of MongoDB and observing some unexpected behavior.  The problem is related to "stemming" aspect of the text indexing feature. The way full text search is described in many articles online, if you have a string "big hunting dogs" in a document's field that is part of the text index, you should be able to search on "hunt" or "hunting" as well as on "dog" or "dogs". MongoDB should normalize or stem the text when indexing and also when searching. So in my example, I would expect it to save words "dog" and "hunt" in the index and search for a stemmed version of this words. If I search for "hunting", MongoDB should search for "hunt".

Well, this is not how it works for me. I am running MongoDB 2.4.8 on Linux with full text search enabled. If my record has value "big hunting dogs", only searching for "big" will produce the result, while searches for "hunt" or "dog" produce nothing. It is as if the words that are not in their "normalized" form are not stored in the text the index (or stored in a way it cannot find them). Searches using $regex operator work fine, that is I am able to find the document by searching on a string like /hunting/ against the field in question.

I tried dropping and recreating the full text index - nothing changed. I can only find the documents containing the words on their "normal" form. Searching for words like "dogs" or "hunting" (or even "dog" or "hunt") produces no results.

Do I misunderstand or misuse the full text search operations or is there a bug in MongoDB?

Comment: You did read the part that says "beta" didn't you. Also the same question was asked just [today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750643/mongodb-full-text-index-full-text-search-stemming)

Comment: Neil, thank you for the reference. I did see the question you are referring too. If you looks closer, our problems are quite different. The author of the other questions complaints about a subtle deficiency in stemming implementation which does not allow MongoDB to recognize derivatives of certain non-standard English plurals (like mice or criteria). My complaint is that stemming does not work in my environment at all even with standard plurals. If I have word "seasons" in my document I cannot find the document using full-text search. This word works fine for the author of the other post.

Comment: Can you provide a an example document or 2 and the commands you are using to create the index and run the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael,

The "language" field (if present) allows each document to override the
language in which the stemming of words would be done. I think, as
you specified to MongoDB a language which it didn't recognize ("ENG"),
it was unable to stem the words at all. As others pointed out, you can use the
`language_override` option to specify that MongoDB should be using some
other field for this purpose (say "lang") and not the default one ("language").

Below is a nice quote (about full text indexing and searching) which
is exactly related to your issue. It is taken from this book.

*"MongoDB: The Definitive Guide, 2nd Edition"*

**Searching in Other Languages**

> When a document is inserted (or the index is first created), MongoDB looks at the
>   indexes fields and stems each word, reducing it to an essential unit. However, different
>   languages stem words in different ways, so you must specify what language the index
>   or document is. Thus, text-type indexes allow a  "default_language" option to be
>   specified, which defaults to  "english" but can be set to a number of other languages
>   (see the online documentation for an up-to-date list).
>   For example, to create a French-language index, we could say:

`> db.users.ensureIndex({"profil" : "text", "interets" : "text"}, {"default_language" : "french"})`

> Then French would be used for stemming, unless otherwise specified. You can, on a
>   per-document basis, specify another stemming language by having a "language" field
>   that describes the document’s language:

`> db.users.insert({"username" : "swedishChef", "profile" : "Bork de bork", language : "swedish"})`

What the book does not mention (at least this page of it doesn't) is that
one can use the `language_override` option to specify that MongoDB
should be using some other field for this purpose (say "lang") and
not the default one ("language").

Answer (score 3):

After a fair amount of experimenting and scratching my head I discovered the reason for this behavior. It turned out that the documents in the collection in question had attribute 'language'. Apparently the presence and the value of that attribute made these documents non-searchable. (The value happened to be 'ENG'. It is possible that changing it to 'eng' would make this document searchable again. The field, however, served a completely different purpose). After I renamed the field to 'lang' I was able to find the document containing the word "dogs" by searching for "dog" or "dogs".

I wonder whether this is expected behavior of MongoDB - that the presence of language attribute in the document would affect the text search.

Answer (score 0):

In http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/ take a look at the **language_override** option when setting up the index. It allows you to change the name of the field that should be used to define the language of the text search. That way you can leave the "language" property for your application's use, and call it something else (e.g. searchlang or something like that).

Comment: sorry I know this is old, but if i dont have any field named "language", and by default the index is created with a "language_override" field, does it overrides my "default_language" with some undefined or NULL value?