# How does MongoDB process unsupported languages?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have documents that have a text field.  The text could be one of dozens of languages, though most are supported by MongoDB (English, Russian, German, French, etc.).  There is also a language field which tells MongoDB the language of the document's text field.  How does MongoDB handle unsupported languages, like Urdu or Swahili?  A [post about MDB 2.](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/06/26/mongodb-full-text-search/)4 suggests indexing cannot be performed on unsupported languages.  An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766998/stemming-does-not-work-properly-for-mongodb-text-index?rq=1) suggests that indexing, but not lemmatization, is performed on unsupported languages.  For my case, it is fine if no lemmatization is performed.

Comment: you can encode the language and then store it, to have the indexing.

Comment: But what if the language is something like Arabic that MongoDB does not stem (because the Snowball software it uses does not)?

Comment: actually I did a project on arabic a while ago and it stored arabic just fine in the database, no encoding required, and the indexing was working fine too, not sure about the text indexing though.

Comment: Yea, I think it indexes but just doesn't lemmatize.